# Как спрятать элемент за пределами блока

Tags: html, css

Есть картинка, мне ее надо скрыть на половину, то есть я на половину ее загоняю за пределы блока в котором она находится.

Как я могу ту часть которая вылазит скрыть ? Что бы было вроде обрезанной картинки
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добавить `overflow:hidden` контейнеру, который содержит картинку и прочий контент. Тогда всё, что за пределами контейнера, будет скрыто

Comment: Спасибо, помогло) Это круто!

Comment: Оформил в виде ответа. Ответ можно принять галочкой слева от ответа. Был рад помочь!

Comment: Ок, приму, тут ограничитель в 10 минут)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Необходимо добавить `overflow: hidden` контейнеру, который содержит картинку и прочий контент. Тогда всё, что за пределами контейнера, будет скрыто.

Источник: [Свойство overflow](https://webref.ru/css/overflow)

> `hidden` Отображается только область внутри элемента, остальное будет
>   скрыто.

Answer (score 2):

Создай div блок и помести в него изображение. В стиле для div укажи `overflow: hidden;`

```css
.test {
  height: 524px;
  width: 250px;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
}
h1 {float: right;}
```

```html
<div class='test'>
  <img src='http://cdn1.macworld.co.uk/cmsdata/features/3605337/MacbookAir11_lifestyle_15_thumb800.jpg'>
</div>
<h1>Половина изображения</h1>
```